# Reading and producing an extra return value in FLAGS in LLVM

Tags: assembly, x86, llvm, eflags

I was watching Herb Sutter's talk on CppCon 2019, and one idea is to use control flag register bits to mark that an exception has been produced during a function call. E.g. (assuming x86 target) a function that raises an error could emit a `stc` instruction just before returning, and the caller could execute a conditional jump immediately after it returns to check if an error should be handled. It's smart, its efficient (much better than returning the condition flag in a separate register), and it's simple.

However, how would one go about implementing something like this within LLVM? I suppose that one can use `MachineBasicBlock` to emit flag set intructions, but does one have a guarantee that LLVM won't insert an instruction afterwards that might change the flag value? Also, how would one test for the flag value and jump to a LLVM IR block?

Note that my motivation is purely curiosity. I am not actually working on a compiler — I just want to know how these things work.